# AMADEUS API Error on credentials when requesting on production environment

Tags: api, amadeus

I'm trying to use your AMADEUS API but i have trouble to display hotels offers on production environment ..

Note that everything is ok on sandbox.

On https://api.amadeus.com endpoint I do :

1. /v1/security/oauth2/token to get an access token
2. then add the access token as bearer authentication
3. Then launch the request /v2/shopping/hotel-offers/?cityCode=NCE

((( Same as the sandbox )))

Here the response :

```
"errors": [
        {
            "status": 401,
            "code": 701,
            "title": "Wrong authentication credentials.",
            "source": {
                "pointer": "uri"
            }
        }
    ]
```

So I test the token on /v1/security/oauth2/token/{{XXXXXXXX}}

The token is not expired and approuved.

Anyone to help?

Thank you so much (sorry for english mistakes)

Akim

Comment: It seems the URLs used are not properly built. You need to use https://api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token to get your API token (using a production API Key and API Secret). Then you can call the Hotel Search API using this path: https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/?cityCode=NCE. Take a look at the Authorization guide to see concrete examples: https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/authorization-262

Comment: Hi Anthony, thank you for the answer.
This is exactly what i'm trying ...
Endpoint and requests looks good. 
From sandbox to production, I just change the endpoint and API Key / Secret to be able to to get informations from production

Comment: I'm using the postman collection AMADEUS provide us

Comment: Do we need an extra solution for folders?
Ex. AIR, HOTEL, etc ...

Comment: The only things you need to change from test to production are: the new API key/Secret you get after performing the move to production (and you need to change them in the postman collection credentials). The base path from test.api.amadeus.com to api.amadeus.com. Did you  follow these steps to move to production? https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/moving%20to%20production-743

Comment: Tahnk you for your answer.
Yes, I did.
I respected all the steps. As, I also updated Endpoint, Apikey, Secret with production's informations